# Convert CSV to Grouped JSON

Tags: json, csv, grouping, jq, file-conversion

I have several large CSV's which I would like to export to a particular JSON format but I'm not really sure how to convert it over. It's a list of usernames and urls.

```
b00nw33,harrypotter788.flv
b00nw33,harrypotter788.mov
b00nw33,levitation271.avi
b01spider,schimbvalutar109.avi
...
```

I want to export them to JSON grouped by the username like the following

```
{
  "b00nw33": [
    "harrypotter788.flv",
    "harrypotter788.mov",
    "levitation271.avi"
  ],
  "b01spider": [
    "schimbvalutar109.avi"
  ]
}
```

What is the JQ to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to a simple solution is the generic function `aggregate_by`:

```
# In this formulation, f must either always evaluate to a string or
# always to an integer, it being understood that negative integers
# might be problematic
def aggregate_by(s; f; g):
  reduce s as $x  (null; .[$x|f] += [$x|g]);
```

If the CSV can be accurately parsed by simply splitting on commas, then the desired transformation can be accomplished using the following jq filter:

```
aggregate_by(inputs | split(","); .[0]; .[1])
```

This assumes jq is invoked with the -R (raw) and -n options.

### Output

With the given CSV input, the output would be:

```
{
  "b00nw33": [
    "harrypotter788.flv",
    "harrypotter788.mov",
    "levitation271.avi"
  ],
  "b01spider": [
    "schimbvalutar109.avi"
  ]
}
```

### Handling non-trivial CSV

The above solution assumes that the CSV is as uncomplicated as the sample.  If, on the contrary, the CSV cannot be accurately parsed by simply splitting at commas, a more general parser will be needed.

One approach would be to use the very robust and fast csv2json parser at https://github.com/fadado/CSV

Alternatively, you could use one of the many available "csv2tsv" parsers to generate TSV, which jq can handle directly (by splitting on tabs, i.e. `split("\t")` rather than `split(",")`).

In any case, once the CSV has been converted to JSON, the filter `aggregate_by` defined above can be used.

If you are interested in a jq parser for CSV, you might want to look at `fromcsvfile` (https://gist.github.com/pkoppstein/bbbbdf7489c8c515680beb1c75fa59f2); see also 
the definitions for `fromcsv` being proposed at https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1650#issuecomment-448050902